# Rate Limiting API Requests in Python with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing` in Python to make parallel API requests. I have 8 cores on my machine `mp.cpu_count() == 8` .

I am limited to roughly 6 requests per second. What would be the optimal way to make my API calls and process them?

Example code idea below but it doesn't work as intended. I get rapid-fire amount of 429s and then it backs off 10 seconds, but continues to get 429s again in rapid successsion. My fear is that my computer is sending all 8 cores so fast that it is overwhelming the service and not allowing for any successful calls to come back.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def api_call(iter):

    query = {'api_key': iter[0], 'user_id': iter[1]}
    resp = requests.get(url, params=query)
    if resp.status_code == 200:

        data = resp.json()
        print(data )
        return data
    else:
        # Handle too many requests
        while resp.status_code == 429:
            time.sleep(10) # Back off 10 seconds.
            resp = requests.get(url, params=query)
        else:
            if resp.status_code == 200:
                data = resp.json()
                return data

   
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Assume an iterable with api_key and other data to make request to API and populate query string
    iterable: list = [(api_key, other_data1), (api_key, other_data2)]

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as p:
        try:
            res: list = list(p.map(api_call, iterable))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Terminating Multiprocess due to Keyboard Interrupt")
            p.terminate()
        else:
            p.close()
            p.join()
```

Comment: Please explain *how* "it doesn't work as intended".

Comment: If you are only allowed 6 calls per second, why are you sending out 8 concurrent requests?

Comment: @ScottHunter Good point. In that case, if I set my Pool to only send 4 requests at a time, and ```time.sleep(1/4)``` each time, that may get me desired results?

Comment: If only you had a way to test it...

Comment: @ScottHunter Sarcasm is appreciated! :). It helps to have people like yourself to talk through obvious pitfalls I have as a noob. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may already solved your problem, but one solution worth considering is the use of a [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore) to limit the number of active processes. This has the advantage that you can actually start as many tasks in parallel as you want, and then limit only the critical section that makes the web requests.

For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
sem = mgr.Semaphore(4)


def task(id):
    print(f"start task {id}")
    with sem:
        res = requests.get("http://google.com")
        date_from_header = res.headers["date"]
    print(f"stop task {id}")
    return date_from_header


with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
    res = pool.map(task, range(1, 20))

print(res)
```

Regardless of the size of your pool, this will only ever have four concurrent calls to `requests.get` at any given time. Once the requests is complete, your tasks can execute other code in parallel.

Comment: Awesome. Will check this out.

Comment: Started working with this a bit and it isn't entirely solving my problem but it is working decently.. I am limiting the Semaphore to only 3 (so I dont hit 4/s too quickly) processes and sleeping 1 second after each call is made. My responses sometimes have a lot of 400s (this is correct behavior) so I get through those quite fast but when I start finding some 200s, I appear to hit rate limit slightly after.